# Convert an XML file to another XML file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

How do I transform XML 1 to XML 2 using XSLT? I am new to XSLT.

XML 1  - This is the first XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root type="array">
    <item type="object">
        <a:item xmlns:a="item" item="@id" type="string">_:genid1</a:item>
        <a:item xmlns:a="item" item="@type" type="array">
            <item type="string">http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Datatype</item>
        </a:item>
        <a:item xmlns:a="item" item="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#oneOf" type="array">
            <item type="object">
                <a:item xmlns:a="item" item="@list" type="array">
                    <item type="object">
                        <a:item xmlns:a="item" item="@value" type="string">L</a:item>
                    </item>
                    <item type="object">
                        <a:item xmlns:a="item" item="@value" type="string">Q</a:item>
                    </item>
                    <item type="object">
                        <a:item xmlns:a="item" item="@value" type="string">R</a:item>
                    </item>
                </a:item>   <!-- added by edit -->
            </item>
        </a:item>
    </item>
</root>
```

XML 2 - This is the second XML that I need to convert the first XML to.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root type="array">
    <persons>
        <person person_id = "_genid1"></person>
        <type>
            http//www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Datatype
        </type>
        <oneofs>
            <oneof>
                L|Q|R
            </oneof>
        </oneofs>
    </persons>
</root>
```

Comment: I indented your XML and added a closing tag in your source XML to make the snippet well-formed.

Comment: can you please extend your post with the XSLT that you have tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An XSLT-2.0 solution is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:a="item">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        <persons>
            <person person_id="{substring-after(item/a:item[@type='string'],'_')}" />
            <type><xsl:value-of select="item/a:item/item[@type='string']" /></type>
            <oneofs>
                <oneof><xsl:value-of select="item/a:item[@item='http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#oneOf']/item[@type='object']/a:item/item/a:item" separator="|" /></oneof>
            </oneofs>
        </persons>    
        <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root type="array">
   <persons xmlns:a="item">
      <person person_id=":genid1"/>
      <type>http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Datatype</type>
      <oneofs>
         <oneof>L|Q|R</oneof>
      </oneofs>
   </persons>
</root>
```

Comment: In reality,<oneof> is over 128000 characters and I need to split it 16 times into <oneof1>first 8000 characters</oneof1><oneof2>next 8000 characters</oneof2>. How do I do that? Since the limit of a field in sql server variable is 8000 chars when I read it and try to insert it?

Comment: @user9566024: This is a different question. Ask it on SO and combine both answers. With XSLT-2.0 it should be possible to split that string.